# Shiny ui.r and server.r - I can't figure out the code to make the app work

Tags: r, shiny

This is a linear regression on mtcars data set in R Studio. I am trying to create the app. No luck.  Working on it for days. Doesn't help that I am new to programming. Thanks for the help.

Is this right?

```
#server.r
data(mtcars)
mtdata<-mtcars
fit<-lm(mpg~cyl+hp+wt+qsec+am+gear,data=mtcars)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {



    formulaText <- reactive({
            #Not sure what this does.
            paste("mpg ~", input$variable) 
    })


    output$caption <- renderText({  # Not sure what this does.
            formulaText()
    })

  # I am lost here. I think this part needs to 'mate up' with ui.r
    output$mpgPlot <- renderPlot({  
            boxplot(as.formula(formulaText()),  # I don't understand.
                    data = mtdata,
                    outline = input$outliers) # I don't understand.
    })
})# I don't understand.


# ui.R
#fit<-lm(mpg~cyl+hp+wt+qsec+am+gear,data=mtcars)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Guess which variables affect MPG!"),
  # I understand sliders, radio buttons. There is a disconnect between ur
# and server.
    fluidRow(
  # I understand this.         
            column(3,
                   radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Cylinders"), # I understand.
                                choices = list("4 Cyl" = 4, "6 Cyl" =6, # I understand.
                                               "8 Cyl" = 8),selected = 1)),
                   radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Number of Gears"),
                                choices = list("3" = 3, "4" =4,
                                        "5" = 5),selected = 1),
 #I understand this.

            column(3,
                   selectInput("select", label = h3("Transmission Type"),
                               choices = list("Manual " = 1, "Automatic" = 
2), selected = 1)),

            fluidRow(                     
            column(3,
                   sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Horse Power"),
                               min = 52, max = 230, step = 5,value = 52),
                   sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Weight, in tons"),
                               min = 1.513, max = 5.42,step = .1, value = 
"min" ),
                   sliderInput("slider3", label = h3("Quarter Mile, in 
Seconds"),
                               min = 14.60, max = 22.90, step = .1, value 
  # I don't understand.  
    ="min" )),    # I don't understand.
            mainPanel(     # I don't understand.
    h3(textOutput("caption")),  # I don't understand this.
            plotOutput("mpgPlot") # I don't understand this.            
    )         # I don't understand.
    )         # I don't understand.
    )         # I don't understand.
    ))
```

Comment: Can you share your ui.R code as well?

Comment: Hi Raphael. Both ui.r and server.r are above. I will pay you if you help me. I am not kidding.

Comment: Have you gone through the [shiny - getting started](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) lessons?

Comment: If you still haven't found any answers, I could try to help you on Sunday.  Let me know if you still need help.

Comment: Raphael - Sorry for the delayed reply. I will def need help in a few days. Is it possible to pm me and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the input that server.R is expecting from ui.R is not defined (`input$variable` and `input$outliers`). If you add the following controllers to your ui.R you will have a working Shiny app

```
radioButtons("variable", label=h3("Variable"),
             choices = list("Cylinders"="cyl",
                            "Gears"="gear",
                            "Transmission"="am",
                            "Horse Power"="hp",
                            "Weight, in tons"="wt",
                            "Quarter Mile, in seconds"="qsec"),
             selected="cyl"),
checkboxInput("outliers", "Show outliers", FALSE))
```

Comment: If you are available for consulting, please let me know. I would like to have someone I can contact when I have questions. I will pay you hourly or per incident. Is that ok?

Comment: I would recommend checking out http://shiny.rstudio.com/, they have some really nice tutorials over there. I think that would be a much quicker way of learning shiny. In the mean time I took some liberties with your app, and created a github repository (https://github.com/DGKarlsson/mtcars_shiny), where I also tried to add some explanatory comments. If you have further questions you can always post them here.

Comment: I will check it out and appreciate your help!! You went above and beyond the call. Thank you. Are you available for consulting? I need help.